# Buscando valor null com get na Entity do Doctrine

Tags: doctrine, php-7, doctrine-2, symfony, symfony4

Opa tudo bem? Estou com um problema em relação a valores `NULL`
com `Doctrine`. O que acontece: Eu tenho alguns campos numa tabela do banco aonde eu guardo alguns valores para futuras validações, estes campos são `nullable = true`. Vou dar um exemplo: Quando eu gero um `token`, eu automaticamente gero uma data para ele, e quando este `token` é utilizado, eu passo valores `NULL` para o campo `validateToken`, que guarda a data que foi gerado, quanto para o `token`. Para definir este `NULL` no `setter` está tranquilo, o problema é quando vou buscar pelo `getter` o `getValidateToken()` ou o `getTonken()` para fazer alguma verificação e ele está `NULL` neste caso ele me diz que preciso retornar um `DateTime` no `getValidateToken()` e `string` no `getToken()` e esta retornando `NULL`. Segue abaixo o meu código e o erro.

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $token;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $validateToken;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getToken(): string
{
    return $this->token;
}

/**
 * @param string $token
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setToken(string $token = null): User
{
    $this->token = $token;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getValidateToken(): \DateTime
{
    return $this->validateToken;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $validateToken
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setValidateToken(\DateTime $validateToken = null): User
{
    $this->validateToken = $validateToken;
    return $this;
}
```

Sei que posso remover o : string e o : \DateTime mas deve ter um forma de fazer sem remover.

Valeu

Answer (score 0):

Eai.. olhem só.. acabei descobrindo como resolver o problema.. É só usar o `type hinting` do `php7` e colocar um `?` antes de definir o retorno. Assim:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getToken(): ?string
{
    return $this->token;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getValidateToken(): ?\DateTime
{
    return $this->validateToken;
}
```

E está pronto.